git clone --depth 1 & .git/config.lock
I use git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/... to get repositories of useful code that I'm not involved in the development of onto my various machines. Occasionally I get a query about .git/config.lock, such as this:
PS> git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim
Rename from ...git/config.lock to ...git/config failed. Should I try again? (y/n)

So I usually respond y, but I've two questions about this:

Where's the documentation for .git/config.lock ?
Is there an option of git clone to avoid having to answer that question ?

